# CSV file always picks the lowest price

Tags: excel, magento, csv, magento-1.8

Hi I am using Magento and an extension called matrix rates, they use .CSV files to store the data for the post codes saying what post code has what delivery charge. The problem I have got is that it only picks the smallest delivery charge for every single postcode when it should look at the rate for the post code first and then if there isn't one pick the flat rate. I was just wondering if anybody has any ideas.

My excel sheet is like this>>

> Country | Region/State | City | Zip/Postal Code From |Zip/Postal Code To | Weight From | Weight To | Shipping Price | Delivery Type
>
> ---
>
> GBR | *    | - | - | 0 | 9999 | 9999 | Websales Shipping (WS01)
>
> ---
>
> GBR | * | - | - | AB37% | 0 | 9999 | 65 | Websales Shipping (WS01)

Comment: You do realize that your first row only has 8 columns?  You have 9 column headers.  Looks like you are missing the price column from the first column.

Answer (score 0):

Without more details, your pseudo-code (or, pseudo-formula) could look like this:

```
=if(
    vlookup([postCode], [PostCodeShipRateTable], [rateColumn]) >0, 
    [postcodeRate],
    [flatRate]
)
```

[flatRate] could also be a vlookup to another rate table if nec.